# Is there a conventional list of pollution categories to consider in calculations?

Tags: reference-request, environmental-economics

In researching economic damage from various pollutants, I often find that it's very random sources that inform me of various pollutants I need to be mindful of in calculations. Is there any kind of overarching list of known problematic pollutants that one needs to consider in calculations for environmental factors?

For instance, you might have pesticides, heavy metal aerosols, heavy metal colloids and solutions, fertilizer runoff, sewage, etc. But, how do I know there aren't more? There must be some kind of standard list, maybe the European Union or one of the environmental agencies in North America has a list of pollution categories that damage the environment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears more suitable for Earth Science SE (which includes environmental sciences and has a pollution tag).